# Determine excution time for µController, by using a normal PC

Tags: c

I have a C-program running on my PC (I run Fedora and use Eclipse).
Now i need to know/guess, how fast this code would be executed on a µController.

**What i have done:**
My first try was using the clock() function. But this way i also count a lot of time, at which my os is doing something like loading a library, allocating memory. The time measured with this method is orders of magnitude greater than, what the needed execution time should be.

For more accuracy i informed myself about profiling. I installed and used Perf. Now this tells me, that my program runs in about 20.000 cycles/samples.
This could mean an execution time in less than a millisecond instead of seconds that are measured with the above method.

I asked myself: How many instructions my PC and a µController could handle in one cycle. As a first guess, i look a the STM32F407IG and what that µController could do. 
It has got a single precision floating point unit. Therefore i made sure, to use only floats(4Byte) and no doubles, because they would be emulated by software, which is very slow. 
The main operation in my program is an FFT. This should be handled well by the µController, because i has DSP instructions (they are made to allow to effectively do things like FFT). It also is bench-marked with 1.25 DMIPS/MHz. (Dhrystone 2.1) This says, that it can handle integer operations pretty well and need in most cases less than one cycle.
**Question**
Is it right, that the µController should handle my program in about or less than 20.000 Cycles? 
Can i assume the execution time to be cycles divided by frequency? Or specific for my case: 20.000 Cycles / 168 MHZ?
I only need to know, if this rough guess is right. That i won't get the very exact time, does not matter.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense. Any performance tests for the microcontroller has to be performed with that MCUs architecture in mind. It is possible that the "perf" program has support for your given ARM Cortex, but it will still just be a rough approximation.

The advantage of microcontrollers is that you don't have to rely on such fluffy "best guess" profilers, but you can actually measure the real execution time live. This is done by toggling an I/O pin at relevant places in your program, then use an oscilloscope to measure the execution time. You cannot write microcontroller software without an oscilloscope, it is a mandatory tool and the only one giving trustworthy performance measurements, end of story.

**EDIT**

If you have no hardware available, the best way to "guess" is to get a disassembler for your MCU, count the number of instructions (or CPU ticks if available) in your program, then multiply it with the oscillator frequency to get the total execution time.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that i just don't have that µC atm. My task is to say, if i can use a µC (and witch one) or if i need something bigger like a fpga. I will make good use of my oscilloscope at the time i get my µC.  I need no well suited performance test. I rather want to know if my code can be executed in a matter of milliseconds or not. If this guess is wrong by 2 or 3 times that won't be a problem.

Comment: @Kai Can't you just buy an evaluation board and give it a try? Picking the right MCU to handle a certain execution time is otherwise just a qualified guess. I updated my answer with a better way to guess. Your calculations should use microseconds or smaller as the time unit, or you are doing it wrong. One millisecond is an eternity even for a sluggish 8 bit MCU from the 80s.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a simple task.

First: your µC probably has a different archictecture and a different instruction set than your PC. Some operations your PC can do in 1 cycle while your µC can't, for others your µC might behave better. Your PCs processor has different number of registers, you have SSE units, Floating point, CRC32 in hardware etc. Your µC might have different DSP units etc.

Second: You probably use two different compilers for these two different architectures which also implement special optimizations.

Third: Memory behavior: your PC has a huge cache compared to your µC.

To answer your question: to get a more solid estimate you will need an instruction set simulator on your PC. In the simulator the execution time is much slower but you get a really good idea about how many isntructions your program takes.
Together with the µC Clock-speed and a guesstimate on parallelism and cache-hits of your program you can then estimate the time it really takes.

Long story short, profile it on the target.

Comment: Thanks you! I will try to set up a simulator.